# EF Core 1.1.0 Migrations on other servers (not development)

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When development is finished and TFS (VSTS) takes over. The build completes successfully and the artifact directory contains the published website via a build definition. The Release Manager is then triggered, and takes over and creates a website in an environment, the website files are copied to the environment and the website started. All good so far.

Missing the Database migration steps here...

Now someone starts the server and it fails because the database has not been migrated. How do we do that? The EF Tools were not copied to that environment, in fact we can't even run dotnet.exe because the core sdk has not been deployed onto that environment either. so even if we had the tools, we can't execute them.

In EF 6.x it was easy cause we could just copy migrate.exe as part of the artifacts, and run that on the environment after the files were copied. As I understand it, the EF Tools are now a DLL (ef.dll) that has to be run by dotnet.exe. Does this mean that all web servers now need Core SDK to perform migrations?

Other details about my project setup:
asp.net.core application being deployed onto a QA server for testing. This is not a dev box, does not have VS2015 installed, does not have Core SDK installed.

#### Update:  EF.EXE is part of preview3 and 4.

This solves the requirement for "dotnet.exe" being installed.  I can copy that into the artifacts drop like I used to with migrate.exe.  Is this the proposed solution by the EF Team?

Comment: What server are you deploying to? IIS web server on Windows? Or Kestrel on Linux by configuring reverse proxy on Nginx/Apache web server?

Comment: You need to apply any pending migrations to the database regardless of whether you're deploying to IIS or Kestrel using `dotnet ef database update`. And as far as I can tell, doing that requires you to install .NET Core SDK on your server. Have you tried installing it on your servers? It should work if you did. Otherwise, I won't work.

Comment: using dotnet works fine, it is done many times over during the development cycle.  Updating both remote and local databases works fine in development.  However this question is part of the release management cycle where developers can't access or run these commands on the servers and development kits are not part of the installation.  I appreciate your reply and it may come down to this as a work-around, but there must be another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EF.EXE is part of preview3 and 4.
>
> This solves the requirement for "dotnet.exe" being installed. I can copy that into the artifacts drop like I used to with migrate.exe. Is this the proposed solution by the EF Team?

Yes. Do this.

Also see issue [#6313](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6313) where we want to make this experience a little easier on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run .NET Core web application on your server, you need to install .NET Core SDK (currently 1.1) on your servers. Doing so will give you the `dotnet` command so that you can execute `dotnet ef database update` on your server environment to update the database to a specified migration.

Comment: The SDK is actually needed?  what for?  So SDK doesn't stand for Software Development Kit, it actually means runtime components now? Sorry, I'm going to hold out for more information as I can't see the DevOp guys liking to have to include an SDK on a production box.

Comment: Yes, installing the SDK is what gives you the `dotnet` command on your machine. I understand your concern since .NET Core is currently in version 1.1.0-preview4 (i.e., RTM). But that's the risk you're taking for early adopting this framework. In fact, your .NET Core app is probably using `project.json` and now they are going to change it back to `.csproj`.

Comment: I realize there are risks in early adoption, and I understand that things are in flux, but version 1.0 was a full release supporting in production environments, and we are now nearly onto 1.1.0 so I would have thought this question would have a solution.

Comment: I think you are right when you say "there must be another solution". In order to publish to IIS, use Web Deploy v3.6 and HttpPlatformHandler. For more information: [Publishing to IIS with Web Deploy using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy). Not sure if you already tried this...sorry I couldn't be more helpful

Comment: also, refer to [Publishing to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis)

Comment: Thank you,  I found those linked posts and though useful, generate publish scripts from within Visual Studio.  Our DevOps team only use the TFS web portal and manage releases from with the Releases tab and add/edit/remove environments from there. We (the devs) provide all the initial scripts, etc for our applications, but then it is up to DevOps to fill in the blanks (users, passwords, servers, etc).